# Javascript function order

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, geolocation

I want to execute functions in order but i constantly get 1,3,4,2 in console.Because of that ltt and lott remains 0 in function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm.Any ideas?Thanks in advance.

```
var ltt=0;
var lott=0;

if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ajmo);
    console.log('1');
}

function ajmo(position){
    console.log('2');
    window.ltt=position.coords.latitude;
    window.lott=position.coords.longitude;
    document.write(window.ltt);
}

console.log('3');
document.write(window.ltt);
document.write("kurac:" + getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(45.332497,14.436384));

function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1){
    console.log('4');   
  //second
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(ltt-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lott-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(ltt)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Comment: `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous which is why 3 fires before 2 and 4.

Comment: is there a way to make it synchronous or to fire before?

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous in general so simply writing the code won't ensure the way it's run, you must use proper callback functions for that. When you use callback functions you ensure that the code within them are not run until they're ready to be run.

Comment: any idea how to do it in my code?

Comment: For esthetic: try to regroup the function definition on the top of the program, to make it more readable. And it's always better to define a function before calling it (lke ajmo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes will ensure that all console messages are in order 1,2,3,4

```
var ltt=0;
var lott=0;

if (navigator.geolocation){
    console.log('1');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ajmo);
}

function ajmo(position){
    console.log('2');
    window.ltt=position.coords.latitude;
    window.lott=position.coords.longitude;
    document.write(window.ltt);

   console.log('3');
   document.write(window.ltt);
   document.write("kurac:" + getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(45.332497,14.436384));
}


function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1){
    console.log('4');   
  //second
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(ltt-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lott-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(ltt)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use global variables here. Simply include the call to `getDistanceFromLatLonInKm` within `ajmo`, and this will ensure that your code does things in the right order.

```
// call getLocation
getLocation();

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ajmo);
  }
}

function ajmo(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;

  // don't use document.write - it's considered bad practice
  // this will get access to an element with id="out"
  var out = document.getElementById('out');

  // now pass lat and lng as new parameters into getDistanceFromLatLonInKm
  out.innerHTML = 'kurac:' + getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(45.332497, 14.436384, lat, lng);
}

// now use the lat/lng arguments instead of the global variables
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat_origin, lon_origin, lat_pos, lng_pos) {
  var R = 6371;
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat_pos - lat_origin);
  var dLon = deg2rad(lng_pos - lng_origin);
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat_origin)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat_pos)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Comment: This is soo much better.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they are being called out of order is because the method "`geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)`" is asynchronous.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation

The (function)object AJMO that you are giving to it is actually used to describe the callback method. The script hits the line and sends an asynchronous request to the function, BUT it isn't going to wait for a response. The execution proceeds forward even though it hasn't heard back yet. The remaining lines are pretty simple with very low overhead so they resolve much, much quicker than the getCurrentPosition method. '2' is executed at the end, but this is only because the method finally "called back" to the success function you created, "AJMO".

If you want to make sure that the code is executed in order you could try this instead.

---

```
var ltt=0;
var lott=0;

function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1){
    console.log('4');   
  //second
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(ltt-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lott-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(ltt)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function ajmo(position){
    console.log('2');
    window.ltt=position.coords.latitude;
    window.lott=position.coords.longitude;
    document.write(window.ltt);

    console.log('3');
    document.write("kurac:" + getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(45.332497,14.436384));
}

if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ajmo);
    console.log('1');
}
```

This puts the calls to '2', '3', and '4' within the successful callback method while still exposing "getDistanceFromLatLonInKm" as a separate function if you need it for some other purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is there a way  to call getDistanceFromLatLonInKm with variables and have a same output.Because in my example this function has hardcoded arguments?

Comment: Wouldn't it be <br />document.write("kurac:" + getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(window.ltt,window.lott));<br />